# Why can't input() in Python 3.6 be placed in an if _ is _: statement like this one?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input

Edited version

```
x = input("Put 'thing' here \n")
if x is 'thing':
    print("Success thingx!")
else:
    print(x)

y = "thing"
if y is 'thing':
    print("Success thingy!")
else:
    print(x)
```

While I expected my result to be

```
Put 'thing' here 
thing
#above is the input
Success thingx!
Success thingy!
```

I got the result

```
Put 'thing' here 
thing
#above is the input
thing
Success thingy!
```

Is there an error in how I am writing this?

Comment: Why do you think you need the `str()` function?

Comment: I originally had it without str(), thought str() would convert it into a string if it was not a string originally and that was the problem.

Comment: `input()` always is a string in  python3. A string is obviously always a string

Comment: Regardless of str(), input() apparently doesn't give 'thing' if one types in thing as the input.

Comment: the 2nd     thing      was the input. I added str() more out of paranoia.

Comment: Because you seem to not understand `is` vs `==`

Comment: Ah. that was the problem. I'm just a newbie at python trying to learn more around it, so thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **is** operator checks for identity. *cpython* use string interning to use the same **str** objects in different places. But, when using the **input** method a new **str** object is created and not the interned one

**is** =>   id(x1) == id(x2)

adding some **id** prints

```
x = str(input("Put 'thing' here \n"))
print('x', id(x))
print('thing', id('thing'))
if x is 'thing':
    print("Success thingx!")
else:
    print(x)

y = str("thing")
print('y', id(y))
if y is 'thing':
    print("Success thingy!")
else:
    print(x)
```

then the output is

```
thing
x 42666048
thing 42737760
thing
y 42737760
Success thingy!
```

you should use **==** if you want to test for equality

Answer (score 0):

you're confusing `is` with `==`

The `is` operator checks exact identity, that the two objects are actually the same exact object.  This is implementation-specific and often the case for interned strings (small string literals) in cpython.  The return value of `input()` is dynamically constructed and doesn't participate in interning here.

You want to use `==` to check equality between strings.  Reserve `is` for singletons such as `True`, `False`, `None`, `...` (`Ellipsis`), `NotImplemented`, types, etc.